# prevent the size of the layout when the soft key board appear

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/select_part"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:ems="18"
        android:textSize="15sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/part_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.6" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Move to Purchase Order" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Move to Invoice info" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here I used above layout to show a list view and `TextView` and `Button`.But when the soft-keyboard appear the size of the key board getting small.In order to prevent that i used the folowing line inside the activty

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

but this give me nothing

Comment: Try to change it to android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". More at this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"` in `manifest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan`

Answer (score 0):

why dont you put your whole `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout > <!-- your layout here-->
</ScrollView>
```